# What are the correct characters for 直接用自己的bǎolǐng象却换掉了对方的这个c3马 describing Caruana's recent surprise chess move?

Tags: terminology, transcription

In [this chess video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-fwCZfvKmE&t=75), chess grandmaster 杨凯淇 describes a recent remarkable chess game where super-GM Caruana violated a chess principle:

> 在这个局面当中，走了象吃c3。直接用自己的**bǎolǐng**象却换掉了对方的这个c3马。
> <sub>杨凯淇</sub>

I don't know what "bǎolǐng" means here, although I'd guess bǎo is 保.  In English, we'd call the bishop the "[fianchetto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fianchetto)ed bishop", borrowing from Italian.  I'm also not sure if 却 is correct.  So we might translate this to:

> In this position, [he] moved the bishop to c3.  [He] directly swaps his fianchettoed bishop for his opponent's c3 knight.

**Question**: What are the correct characters for 直接用自己的bǎolǐng象却换掉了对方的这个c3马?

Comment: Also that 却 might be 去 [qù]… seems to me there is no abruptness here, yet this “却” seems odd…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called ["堡垒象"](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%A0%A1%E5%9E%92%E8%B1%A1).

Not bao3ling3, but bao3lei3.